# Mojolicious::Lite jQuery autocomplete Question

Tags: jquery, perl, autocomplete, mojolicious

The autocomplete doesn't work: Is the whole approach wrong or have I made only some errors?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings; use 5.014; use utf8;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $table = 'my_table';

get '/input' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render( 'input' );
};

get '/search_db' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $col = $self->param( 'col' );
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT $col FROM $table" );
    $sth->execute();
    my $ref;
    while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {
        push @$ref, @$row;
    }
    $self->render( json => $ref );
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ input.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="/js_local/development-bundle/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js_local/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/js_local/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/js_local/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="/js_local/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#vorname").autocomplete({
                source: '/search_db?col=vorname',
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Vorname:</td><td><input type="text" id="vorname" 
        name="vorname" autocomplete="off"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Nachname:</td><td><input type="text" id="nachname" 
        name="nachname" autocomplete="on" /></td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I am one step further: now after the second character I get all the names appear as a selection.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your javascript console? Are the paths to the js files correct?

Comment: Ok, what shows up in your web server's logs?

Comment: Are you sure you never reached `die $col;` line? For me it looks like your request was executed and died at that line, so you see code 500. Also maybe it would be good to attach console output or log content when Mojolicious dies?

Comment: When I remove the `die $col;` I get the same error.

Comment: @sid_com you really need to show server's log where it dies

Comment: I had a log-directory (I forgot), so the server-log didn't appear on the console, but in the log-file.

Comment: If I put now a `die Dumper $ref;` at the end of the `/search_db` routine in the server-log appears `[error] $VAR1 = ['John','Ruby'...]` (each time, I enter a character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use DBI;

my $table = 'my_table';
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ) or die $DBI::errstr;

get '/eingabe' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render( 'eingabe' );
};

get '/search_db/:col' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $col = $self->param( 'col' );
    my $term = $self->param( 'term' );
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 
                  "SELECT DISTINCT $col FROM $table WHERE $col LIKE ?" 
              );
    $sth->execute( $term . '%');
    my $ref;
    while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {
            push @$ref, @$row;
    }
    $self->render( json => $ref );
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ eingabe.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="/development-bundle/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            var data = [];
            var form = document.forms[0];
            var formEls = form.elements;
            var elLen = formEls.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < elLen; ++i ) {
                if ( formEls[i].type != 'submit' ) {
                    data.push( formEls[i].id );
                }
            }
            var dLen = data.length;
            for ( i = 0; i < dLen; i++ ){
                $( "#" + data[i] ).autocomplete({
                    delay: 100,
                    minLength: 2,                                 
                    source: '/search_db/' + data[i]
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Vorname:</td><td><input type="text" id="vorname" 
            name="vorname" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nachname:</td><td><input type="text" id="nachname" 
            name="nachname" autocomplete="on" /></td></tr>
        </table><br />
        <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got an extra comma after minLength:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#vorname").autocomplete({ 
        source: '/search_db?col=vorname', 
        minLength: 2, 
    }); 
});
```

Try that for a start!

Comment: Removed the comma in the example

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you declare `$table`? Running your both scripts from command line i got:

```
Global symbol "$table" requires explicit package name at mojo_test2.pl line 19.
mojo_test2.pl had compilation errors.
```